# A WCF Service Hosted as Windows Service throws timeout error

Tags: wcf, windows-services, windows-server-2003

We have a very simplistic WCF service(referred to as ACS) hosted as a Windows Service on a Windows 2003 box. This service exposes an Http end point. We use TopShelf to configure the Windows Host that is configured as a Windows Service. On the startup of this service, it sends a "Register" message to another WCF Service which is hosted on a separate box under IIS. However this Register message from ACS to the IIS/WCF service is not transmitted and the ACS fails to start. The error we get is

> The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:02:00.
>   Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase
>   the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this
>   operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout., Inner
>   Exception: The HTTP request to '{http based IIS WCF end point here}'
>   has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:00. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

If we remove this start-up call from ACS, then ACS starts and works normally. The web based service can call into ACS if it needs to and get job done.

This is our sample code to start ACS (_acs, _ars etc get passed in as constructor dependencies)

```
 HostFactory.Run(c =>
            {
                c.Service<IACSInterface>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(() => _acs);
                    s.WhenStarted(x =>
                    {
                        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(x);
                        _serviceHost.Open();
                        string domainName = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
                        string fullyQualifiedMachineName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + "." + domainName;
                        _ars.RegisterMachine(fullyQualifiedMachineName, AgentStatus.Available.ToString());

                    });
                    s.WhenStopped(x =>
                    {
                        if (_serviceHost != null && (_serviceHost.State != CommunicationState.Closed && _serviceHost.State != CommunicationState.Closing))
                            _serviceHost.Close();
                    });
                });
                c.SetDisplayName("servicename");
                c.SetServiceName("realSErviceName");
                c.SetDescription("The service that does something awesome.");
                c.RunAsLocalSystem();
                c.StartAutomatically();
            }
```

The service is set to start automatically and it is manually configured to run under a domain account who is local admin on the Windows 2003 Box.

While we can increase the time-out value I do not want to do give it an endless timeout. I would want to know what is the reason behind this behaviour and what is the best resolution for this.

Comment: can you get the second WCF service to respond at all?  any error messages returned by it?

Comment: The second (web based) service does not get hit at all.

Comment: In WCF, timeout values apply to both service and client.  It sounds like you've checked the timeouts on the client (ACS) side.  What about the timeouts on the service (IIS) side?

Comment: I have AppFabric logging enabled on the server. the server logs do not show any requests coming in from the client machines that run Windows 2003. The boxes that run Windows 2008 where the service is set to start in Automatic Delayed Start Mode work fine.